# Display loop list where not empty

Tags: php

I have a list of categories and want to display them if they are not empty, as in a product is listed in the category. How would I do this?
Code as is.

```
$category_sql = "SELECT * FROM tm_product_category";
$category_query = mysql_query($category_sql) or die(mysql_error());
$categorylist = mysql_fetch_assoc($category_query); 


<?php do { ?>
<ul><li><a href="category.php?pk_cat_id=<?php echo $categorylist['pk_cat_id'];?>"><?php echo $categorylist['category']; ?></a></ul>
<?php } while ($categorylist = mysql_fetch_assoc($category_query)); ?>
```

I have one table with a list of categories and id's and another table with products and foreign key category id's.

Thanks.

Comment: are empty values stored as NULL?

Comment: and what happened when you did that?

Comment: I think you need this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: dm03514 I would need it to look at what category id's are used in the product table and display those catgories only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this after your query line.

```
<?php

    $selected_category = 'clothing';

    while($category_query_info = mysql_fetch_array($category_query)){

        $product_name = $category_query_info['product_name'];   
        $product_category = $category_query_info['product_category'];                       

        if (($product_category == $selected_category) && (!empty($product_name)) {
            echo "<br>Product Name: " . $product_name;
        }

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
$category_sql = "SELECT * FROM tm_product_category";
$category_query = mysql_query($category_sql) or die(mysql_error());
if($category_query)
{
  //Only print the rows if the $category_query result get some values
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($category_query))
  {
     print_r($row);
  }
}
```